# Encountered "Error: Material-UI: capitalize(string) expects a string argument." when using snackbar in React Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using snackbar in Material-UI, and I encountered `Error: Material-UI: capitalize(string) expects a string argument.`

My code

```
    this.state = {
      snackBarOpenVertical: "bottom",
      snackBarOpenHorizontal: "right",
    };

            <Snackbar
              // Neither of the 2 following approaches works.
              anchorOrigin={"bottom", "right"}
              anchorOrigin={this.state.snackBarOpenVertical, this.state.snackBarOpenHorizontal}

              open={true}
              onClose={this.handleSnackBarClose}
              message="I love snacks"
            />
```

I think the problem is in the `anchorOrigin` field, because it worked when I commented that 2 lines out though I couldn't specify the location of the snackbar that way.

And as I commented above, neither of the 2 approaches works.

Snackbar document:
https://material-ui.com/components/snackbars/

Could anyone point out where I did wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you have added like this `anchorOrigin={{"bottom", "right"}}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](https://material-ui.com/components/snackbars/), `anchorOrigin` takes an object like this:

```
anchorOrigin={{
  vertical: 'bottom',
  horizontal: 'left',
}}
```

You are omitting the inner `{}` and `vertical` and `horizontal` property names in your implementations